# Тестирование на java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, test-automation

Задача: залогиниться на сайт https://accounts.google.com, проверить, что пользователь залогинился. Высвечивается `NullPointerException` в строке c     `WebElement login`

```
public class Test1 {
        WebDriver driver;

        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            File file = new File(".\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("https://accounts.google.com");
        }

        @Test
        public void userLog() {
            System.out.print("Enter ");

            WebElement login=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id=\"identifierId\"]"));
            login.sendKeys("anykoval1356@gmail.com");
            System.out.print("Input name ");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=\"identifierNext\"]")).click();


            WebElement explicitWait1 = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                    .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("password")));

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=\"password\"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("epam1356");
            System.out.print("Input password ");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=\"passwordNext\"]")).click();

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=\"yDmH0d\"]")).click();


            String expectedStr = "Вітаємо, Анна Коваль!";


            WebElement waiting = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                    .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"yDmH0d\"]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/c-wiz/c-wiz/div/div[4]/div/div/header/h1")));
            WebElement Welcome = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"yDmH0d\"]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/c-wiz/c-wiz/div/div[4]/div/div/header/h1"));
            String strOnPage = Welcome.getText();
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Actual result: " + strOnPage);
            System.out.println("Expected result: " + expectedStr);
            Assert.assertEquals(expectedStr, strOnPage);
        }


        @After
        public void tearDown() {
            driver.close();
        }
}
```

Comment: В процедуре userLog() у вас не проинициализирован driver. Скорее всего, ошибка именно в этом.

Comment: Создайте глобальную переменную Webdriver driver и далее используйте только ее.

Comment: Она была создана строчкой выше (public class Test1 { WebDriver driver;). Просто это не отображено как код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

там где `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` убери `WebDriver`.

Должно получится `driver = new ChromeDriver()`